# How do I create cohorts of users from month of first order, then count information about those orders in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, time-series, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use SQL to:

1. Create user cohorts by the month of their first order
2. Sum the total of all the order amounts bought by that cohort all-time
3. Output the cohort name (its month), the cohort size (total users who made first purchase in that month), `total_revenue` (all order revenue from the users in that cohort), and `avg_revenue` (the `total_revenue` divided by the `cohort` size)

Please see below for a SQL Fiddle, with sample tables, and the expected output:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5937

Thanks!!

**Users Table**

```
+-----+---------+
| id  |  name   |
+-----+---------+
|   1 | Adam    |
|   2 | Bob     |
|   3 | Charles |
|   4 | David   |
+-----+---------+
```

**Orders Table**

```
+----+--------------+-------+---------+
| id |     date     | total | user_id |
+----+--------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | '2020-01-01' |   100 |       1 |
|  2 | '2020-01-02' |   200 |       2 |
|  3 | '2020-03-01' |   300 |       3 |
|  4 | '2020-04-01' |   400 |       1 |
+----+--------------+-------+---------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
|   cohort     | cohort_size  | total_revenue  | avg_revenue |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| '2020-01-01' |            2 |            700 |         350 |
| '2020-03-01' |            1 |            300 |         300 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the minimum date for every user and aggregate for them. Then you can aggregate for every such date:

```
with first_orders(user_id, cohort, total) as (
  select user_id, min(ordered_at), sum(total)
  from orders
  group by user_id
)
select to_char(date_trunc('month', fo.cohort), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(fo.user_id), sum(fo.total), avg(fo.total)
from first_orders fo
group by date_trunc('month', fo.cohort)
```

Comment: Thanks @andronicus! One additional layer -- what if I also have a `subscriptions` table, and what I actually want to do is use the `first_subscription` query to create the cohort, but then use the `orders` table for the stats. i.e. for all users who created a subscription in January, what are the cumulative order revenue from this cohort

Comment: @ruby86 you try going for nested select in that case, if you have problems, post it as another question

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to get the first date.  The rest is then aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', first_date) as yyyymm,
       count(distinct user_id), sum(total), sum(total)/ count(distinct user_id)
from (select o.*, min(o.ordered_at) over (partition by o.user_id) as first_date
      from orders o
     ) o
group by date_trunc('month', first_date)
order by yyyymm;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5937/20) is the SQL fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! I can't get the query to run in the JS fiddle though, is there a typo I'm missing?

Comment: @ruby86 . . . One important reason is that the column names in your question and in the fiddle are different.